# Notate in the decimal fraction form of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ the third digit after the decimal point with $a_n$. What are the limit points of $a_n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I substituted a few natural numbers into $\frac{n}{n+1}$ but I still have no idea, how to solve this problem, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Hint: See what happens when $n\geq 1000$

Comment: Yes, I will get always a $9$, but how can I find a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Write $\dfrac{n}{n+1} = 1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}$. 
Then, for $n\ge1000$, we get
$$
1 > \frac{n}{n+1} = 1-\frac{1}{n+1} > 1 - \frac{1}{1000} = 0.999
$$

Comment: Could you maybe give a little bit more detailled hint?